# Are questions about Santa Claus on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is Santa Claus a Fantasy topic? I think yes, but just want to be sure before doing so.

Comment: What?! A fantasy? How can that be true? I get pressies every year!

Comment: Actually, Santa is Futuristic Sci-Fi. Maybe throw in some alternate-reality steampunk as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We discuss fantasy here, we don't make it. So I'd say a question about the literature about Santa Claus is on-topic. It doesn't have to be about a specific work, it can explore the related myth and tropes transversally. But it does need to have some anchor in existing works.

Now about [your actual question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7825/how-does-santa-claus-get-into-houses-without-a-fireplace): I don't think it's appropriate for this site, because it's not relating to existing works. And judging by the quality of the answers it received, I don't think it's appropriate for Stack Exchange at all. This is more of a topic for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley).

Comment: Questions that don't relate to an existing work are appropriate for [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/). Here's a well received question similar to OP's deleted question: [How does Santa fit down the chimney?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/100799/22818)

Answer (score 22):

No, because as everyone knows, Santa Claus is *real*.

Comment: I know it's real, but there's a lot of speculative works around the real Santa Claus. Could it be on-topic from this point of view?

Comment: Santa apparently *is* real: [Anonymous donors pay off Kmart layaway accounts](http://xfinity.comcast.net/articles/news-general/20111215/US.Layaway.Santas/)

Answer (score 7):

If the question concerns a specific work of fantasy or science-fiction, then yes.

Comment: Our questions aren't limited to specific works.  Most relevantly here, questions regarding creatures and characters from sf&f are on-topic, as long as they can reasonably be answered.

Comment: @Kevin - that's the problem. Questions about santa can't be reasonably answered. They can be wild ass guesses, that are upvoted 'cause everyone (except for meiflein and me apparentlly) loves Santa.

Answer (score 4):

A *bah, humbug* in advance.

We have four [santa-claus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/santa-claus) questions so far, and given the time of year, it's reasonable to consider an increase:

- [How does NORAD track Santa](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7876/how-does-norad-track-santa). How can science-fiction/fantasy expertise provide value here, unless the question was asking how this has been explained in existing works?  If it's purely about tracking a sleigh-type object, then that's better asked elsewhere.
- [Is Santa Claus a Time Lord](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/is-santa-claus-a-time-lord). I personally don't consider any "can we fit a character from universe A into universe B" question as constructive (e.g. [this Star Trek/My Little Pony one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/is-my-little-pony-friendship-is-magic-canon-with-star-trek)).  If it was worded so that it was asking if the Doctor (or another Time Lord) had claimed this in canon, then that would be different, but as-is these seem pure discussion/speculation without value.  However, since the others are on-topic, this perhaps is.
- [How does Santa Claus get into houses without a fireplace](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7825/how-does-santa-claus-get-into-houses-without-a-fireplace). *Closed*.  As the comments point out, this is (as it is currently written) really a parenting question.
- [How to know if a Santa Claus is the real one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7824/how-to-know-if-a-santa-claus-is-the-real-one). *Closed*.

Maybe these are 'fun', and maybe I am just not fun enough, but I see no value here at all.

Answer (score 3):

GO. FOR. IT. YES.

I really want to know what this question is about. Also, does Santa warrant...a ***Santa Grant***?

Comment: All expense paid trip to the North Pole.