# Santa animation questions...which category

Tags: support, scope

I want to find info about an old Santa and reindeer cartoon that lasts maybe 4 minutes.

Where should I post the question please?

Comment: We've discussed this before. If it's a question about Santa the real person, it's off-topic. It's if a work about Santa the fictional character, you're ok; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/are-questions-about-santa-claus-on-topic

Comment: @Valorum What do you mean _fictional_ character? Are you saying Santa isn't real?

Comment: @Amarth - Santa is regularly depicted in [films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Santa_Clause) and [books](https://www.harpercollins.com/9780062748744/santas-husband/). Since these properties are often contradictory, they must be showing a fictionalised version of Santa, a real person.